# How does virtual work method relate to matrix method or FEM in structural analysis?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I understand the relationship of force method and displacement method and how we use them in matrices in FEM. 
How about virtual work? Is it used in matrices and FEM too?

Comment: A more general way to formulate element matrices is using energy methods, which is can be considered as a special case of virtual work. The force and displacement methods are now mostly historical, but useful for teaching the basic ideas of FEM  because they only need "strength of materials" engineering concepts, not "continuum mechanics". Note, the "matrix variables" in a finite element formulation are not necessarily just displacements and rotations - they may also include internal stresses for example.

Comment: I thought the structural analysis programs used displacement method as their basis for FEM. that is not correct? I only wanted to know how virtual work fit in for FEM. Are you saying the FEM software today use virtual work but not displacement methods?